# Under what conditions will my component reload under React-router, and when will these useEffect functions be triggered?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, use-effect

I'm trying to troubleshoot some issues with a site and realized that I don't really understand some React and React-router fundamentals. I am using HashRouter with some optional params to serve my pages:

```
<HashRouter>
    <Route path="/page/:param1?/:param2?/:param3?" component={props => <Component {...props} />} />
    ...
</HashRouter>
```

I tried using BrowserRouter but it would not allow me to navigate directly to the page if params were included. HashRouter does, though I don't know why.

When I go from `https://www.mywebsite.com/#/page` to `https://www.mywebsite.com/#/page/1/2/3` is Component being completely reloaded or not? Is it the same case when reversed? Inside Component, when does `useEffect(() => {}, [])` get called? I have been using it as a substitution for componentDidMount but it seems to trigger multiple times and I don't know why. When does `useEffect(() => {}, [window.location.href])` get called, and is it an appropriate method to check for changes in my params? Would `useEffect(() => {}, [JSON.stringify(props.match.params)])` be better?